# Kotlin: Convert large List to sublist of set partition size

Tags: kotlin

I'm looking for a function equivalent to [Groovy's collate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5283) which would partition a large List into batches for processing. I did see [`subList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-list/sub-list.html) which could be adapted into a similar function but wanted to check and make sure I wasn't missing an in-built or crazy simple alternative to rolling my own.

Comment: This feature is proposed for a future version of Kotlin. https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/window-sliding.md

Answer (score 42, accepted):

***NOTE:*** *For Kotlin 1.2 and newer, please see the [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) and [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) functions that are now in the standard library.  There is no need for a custom solution.*

---

Here is an implementation of a lazy batching extension function which will take a collection, or anything that can become a `Sequence` and return a `Sequence` of `List` each of that size, with the last one being that size or smaller.

Example usage to iterate a list as batches:

```kotlin
myList.asSequence().batch(5).forEach { group ->
   // receive a Sequence of size 5 (or less for final)
}
```

Example to convert batches of `List` to `Set`:

```kotlin
myList.asSequence().batch(5).map { it.toSet() }
```

See the first test case below for showing the output given specific input.

**Code for the function `Sequence<T>.batch(groupSize)`:**

```kotlin
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.batch(n: Int): Sequence<List<T>> {
    return BatchingSequence(this, n)
}

private class BatchingSequence<T>(val source: Sequence<T>, val batchSize: Int) : Sequence<List<T>> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<List<T>> = object : AbstractIterator<List<T>>() {
        val iterate = if (batchSize > 0) source.iterator() else emptyList<T>().iterator()
        override fun computeNext() {
            if (iterate.hasNext()) setNext(iterate.asSequence().take(batchSize).toList())
            else done() 
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit tests proving it works:**

```kotlin
class TestGroupingStream {

    @Test fun testConvertToListOfGroupsWithoutConsumingGroup() {
        val listOfGroups = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).asSequence().batch(2).toList()
        assertEquals(5, listOfGroups.size)
        assertEquals(listOf(1,2), listOfGroups[0].toList())
        assertEquals(listOf(3,4), listOfGroups[1].toList())
        assertEquals(listOf(5,6), listOfGroups[2].toList())
        assertEquals(listOf(7,8), listOfGroups[3].toList())
        assertEquals(listOf(9,10), listOfGroups[4].toList())
    }

    @Test fun testSpecificCase() {
        val originalStream = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

        val results = originalStream.asSequence().batch(3).map { group ->
            group.toList()
        }.toList()

        assertEquals(listOf(1,2,3), results[0])
        assertEquals(listOf(4,5,6), results[1])
        assertEquals(listOf(7,8,9), results[2])
        assertEquals(listOf(10), results[3])
    }


    fun testStream(testList: List<Int>, batchSize: Int, expectedGroups: Int) {
        var groupSeenCount = 0
        var itemsSeen = ArrayList<Int>()

        testList.asSequence().batch(batchSize).forEach { groupStream ->
            groupSeenCount++
            groupStream.forEach { item ->
                itemsSeen.add(item)
            }
        }

        assertEquals(testList, itemsSeen)
        assertEquals(groupSeenCount, expectedGroups)
    }

    @Test fun groupsOfExactSize() {
        testStream(listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), 5, 3)
    }

    @Test fun groupsOfOddSize() {
        testStream(listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 5, 4)
        testStream(listOf(1,2,3,4), 3, 2)
    }

    @Test fun groupsOfLessThanBatchSize() {
        testStream(listOf(1,2,3), 5, 1)
        testStream(listOf(1), 5, 1)
    }

    @Test fun groupsOfSize1() {
        testStream(listOf(1,2,3), 1, 3)
    }

    @Test fun groupsOfSize0() {
        val testList = listOf(1,2,3)

        val groupCountZero =   testList.asSequence().batch(0).toList().size
        assertEquals(0, groupCountZero)

        val groupCountNeg =  testList.asSequence().batch(-1).toList().size
        assertEquals(0, groupCountNeg)

    }

    @Test fun emptySource() {
        listOf<Int>().asSequence().batch(1).forEach { groupStream ->
            fail()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this could be made to NOT be lazy, such as the example that maps to `it.toList()` or to work from a `Collection` instead of a sequence.  But since it is easy to turn them into a `Sequence` it is a good starting point.

Comment: FYI: I think you've got a bug in your `batch` code. The following gets stuck in an endless loop `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).asSequence().batch(2).toList()`.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now, if the elements aren't consumed and you convert to a list, the iterator stays still.  I have to advance the iterator and create something to hold the items not consumed.

Comment: Fixed, easiest answer is to make each batch a `List` created at the time the next group is iterated.  If you write code as you have `.batch(2).toList()` you will materialize all groups into memory at the same time as separate `List` otherwise only one group at a time will materialize.   Code is fixed, tests updated for this case.

Comment: This is great! Thank you both for your time. Love the syntax. Might be a nice addition to the stdlib.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, thanks @JaysonMinard!!

Comment: Awesome answer. It´s been very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 55):

With Kotlin 1.3, according to your needs, you may choose one of the following ways to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html)

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(2, 4, 3, 10, 8, 7, 9)
    val newList = list.chunked(2)
    //val newList = list.chunked(size = 2) // also works
    print(newList)
}

/*
prints:
[[2, 4], [3, 10], [8, 7], [9]]
*/
```

---

## #2. Using [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html)

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(2, 4, 3, 10, 8, 7, 9)
    val newList = list.windowed(2, 2, true)
    //val newList = list.windowed(size = 2, step = 2, partialWindows = true) // also works
    println(newList)
}

/*
prints:
[[2, 4], [3, 10], [8, 7], [9]]
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin 1.2 M2 and later you can use [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) and [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) (see [Kotlin 1.2 M2 is out | Kotlin Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-2-m2-is-out/)). Note that there are `Sequence` variances too (see [kotlin.sequences - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html)).

For versions of Kotlin prior to 1.2 M2 I recommend using [Lists.partition(List, int)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) from `google-guava` (it uses [`java.util.List.subList(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#subList(int,%20int))):

If you are unfamiliar with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) see [CollectionUtilitiesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained) for more details.

You can create your own Kotlin [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for it if you want:

```
fun <T> List<T>.collate(size: Int): List<List<T>> = Lists.partition(this, size)
```

If you want an extension function for mutable lists then in a separate Kotlin file (to avoid platform declaration clashes):

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.collate(size: Int): List<MutableList<T>> = Lists.partition(this, size)
```

If you want something lazy loaded like in [Jayson Minard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504231/3255152) you can use [Iterables.partition(Iterable, int)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)). You might also be interested in [Iterables.paddedPartition(Iterable, int)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#paddedPartition(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) if you want to pad the last sublist if it is smaller than the specified `size`. These return `Iterable<List<T>>` (I don't see much point in making it `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` as [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#subList(int,%20int)) returns an efficient view).

If for some reason you don't want to depend on Guava you can roll your own pretty easily using the [`subList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-list/sub-list.html) function you mentioned:

```
fun <T> List<T>.collate(size: Int): List<List<T>> {
    require(size > 0)
    return if (isEmpty()) {
        emptyList()
    } else {
        (0..lastIndex / size).map {
            val fromIndex = it * size
            val toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + size, this.size)
            subList(fromIndex, toIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
fun <T> List<T>.collate(size: Int): Sequence<List<T>> {
    require(size > 0)
    return if (isEmpty()) {
        emptySequence()
    } else {
        (0..lastIndex / size).asSequence().map {
            val fromIndex = it * size
            val toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + size, this.size)
            subList(fromIndex, toIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose instead of separate files you can also use `@JvmName`. See [Handling signature clashes with @JvmName](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname) for details.

Comment: I like the last short answer, which works nicely for ArrayLists and a variation would work nicely for arrays.  Other lists maybe less performant (i.e. LinkedList).  And for other collections not possible.

Comment: Can you change your answer to protect for behavior when `size` is 0 (div by zero) or negative.

Comment: Good idea @JaysonMinard. Thanks! Added `require(size > 0)` (similar to Guava's partition methods).

Comment: Great, two nice different answers + Guava if people want.

Answer (score 4):

A more simplistic/functional-style solution would be

```
val items = (1..100).map { "foo_${it}" }

fun <T> Iterable<T>.batch(chunkSize: Int) =
   withIndex().                        // create index value pairs
   groupBy { it.index / chunkSize }.   // create grouping index
   map { it.value.map { it.value } }   // split into different partitions


items.batch(3)
```

Note 1: Personally I'd prefer `partition` as a method name here, but it's already present in Kotlin's [stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) to separate a lists into 2 parts given a predicate.

Note 2: The the iterator solution from Jayson may scale better than this solution for large collections.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no built-in function for that yet and while functional and `Sequence`-based implementations from other answers look nice, if you just need is `List` of `List`s, I'd suggest writing a little bit of ugly, imperative, but performant code.

This is my final result:

```
fun <T> List<T>.batch(chunkSize: Int): List<List<T>> {
    if (chunkSize <= 0) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("chunkSize must be greater than 0")
    }
    val capacity = (this.size + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize
    val list = ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>(capacity)
    for (i in 0 until this.size) {
        if (i % chunkSize == 0) {
            list.add(ArrayList(chunkSize))
        }
        list.last().add(this.get(i))
    }
    return list
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Dummy Array

```
 for (i in 0..49){
             var  data="java"
            }
            array.add(data)
```

> Used:

```
  var data=array?.chunked(15)
```

[kotlin's method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html)