# Divide list into parts

Tags: kotlin

Is there a simple way to divide list into parts (maybe some lambda) in Kotlin?

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: that's a feature requested for Kotlin 1.1: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/window-sliding.md

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34498368/3255152

Comment: If you're looking to partition into _two_ parts, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html would do what you want to do. e.g. `list.partition { x -> x < 4 }`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Given the list: `val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` you can use [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html):

```
list.groupBy { (it + 1) / 2 }.map { it.value }
```

Or if your values are not numbers you can first assign an index to them:

```
list.withIndex()
    .groupBy { it.index / 2 }
    .map { it.value.map { it.value } }
```

Or if you'd like to save some allocations you can go a bit more manual way with [foldIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-indexed.html):

```
list.foldIndexed(ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>(list.size / 2)) { index, acc, item ->
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        acc.add(ArrayList(2))
    }
    acc.last().add(item)
    acc
}
```

Comment: For [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html), "the returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the keys produced from the original collection." As such, your first example can be simplified to `list.groupBy { (it + 1) / 2 }.values`.

Comment: Kotlin has [`withIndex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) which can make your second example a bit more readable as well: `list.withIndex().groupBy { it.index / 2 }.values.map { it.map { it.value } }`.

Comment: @mfulton26 thanks for the notice, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 88):

Since Kotlin 1.2 you can use `Iterable<T>.chunked(size: Int): List<List<T>>` function from stdlib (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html).

Comment: This divides a list into parts of size N. It does not divide a list into N parts.

Answer (score 33):

The better answer is actually the one authored by [VasyaFromRussia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2927901/vasyafromrussia).

If you use `groupBy`, you will have to add and index and then post-process extracting the value from an `IndexedValue` object.

If you use `chunked`, you simply need to write:

```
val list = listOf(10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val chunked = list.chunked(2)
println(chunked)
```

This prints out:

```
[[10, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 13):

Nice way of dividing list is by the use of function `partition`. Unlike `groupBy` it doesn't divide list by keys but rather by predicate which gives out `Pair<List, List>` as a result.

Here's an example:

```
val (favorited, rest) = posts.partition { post ->
    post.isFavorited()
}
favoritedList.addAll(favorited)
postsList.addAll(rest)
```

Answer (score 2):

The API says there is a GroupBy function, which should do what you want.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

Or use sublist and break it up yourself

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide a list into N parts.
(and not divide a list into parts of size N)
You can still use the chunked answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48400664/413127

Only, first you need to find your chunk size.

```
val parts = 2
val list = listOf(10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val remainder = list.size % 2 // 1 or 0
val chunkSize = (list.size / parts) + remainder
val chunked = list.chunked(chunkSize)
println(chunked)
```

This prints out

```
[[10, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

or when

`val parts = 3`

This prints out

```
[[10, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Interesting answer in Python here: [Splitting a list into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length/37414115#37414115)