# How to create variables in a for-loop with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Given a maximum list size in parameter `size` and total amount of elements in parameter `elements`, I need to create a list of lists. What is the syntax for creating variables in `for` loops in Kotlin?

The way I'm thinking of going about this is to declare and create lists before elements are added to a list. Then, when a list has reached full capacity, it is switched out for the next list that is empty.

Here is the half-baked code:

```
fun listOfLists(size: Int, vararg elements: String): List<List<String>> {
    var amountOfElements = elements.size
    var currentSubList: List<String> = mutableListOf<String>()
    val numberOfLists: Int = amountOfElements / size + 1

    for (n in 0..numberOfLists) {
        // Code for creating the total number of lists needed
    }

    for (e in elements) {
        if (amountOfElements % size == 0) {
            // Code for switching lists
        }
        amountOfElements--
    }
```

Comment: Is it what you need? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html. The implementation is here, if you are interested: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt.

Comment: @dyukha Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide list into parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699007/divide-list-into-parts)

Comment: The answer and comments helped me to implement but don't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dyukha correctly mentioned, what you need is chunked() function.

```
fun listOfLists(size: Int, vararg elements: String) = 
   elements.asList().chunked(size)
```

Or, if you want to be really efficient, you can also use `asSequence()`:

```
fun listOfLists(size: Int, vararg elements: String) =
    elements.asSequence().chunked(size)
```

`chunked()` doesn't work on `Array`, because it's defined on `Iterable` and `Sequence`, and `Array` doesn't implement any of them.

Comment: does `chunked()` not work with arrays?. I thought `vararg` gives a parameter the qualities of an array.

Comment: Updated my answer.